# create data frames for each ID of another data frame

Tags: r, subset

I looked in the question database but I didn't find an answer, so sorry if I miss something.
The question is very simple: how can I create new data frames based on a column ID of another one?

If this in the original df:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("B0F", 
"B12T", "B1T", "B21T", "B22F", "B26T", "B2F", "B33F", "B3F", 
"B4F", "B7F", "P1", "P21", "P24", "P25", "P27", "P28", "P29"), class = "factor"), 
    EC = c(953L, 838L, 895L, 2170L, 2140L, 1499L, 2120L, 881L, 
    902L, 870L, 541L, 891L, 876L, 860L, 868L, 877L, 3630L, 3400L, 
    2470L, 2330L, 1810L, 2190L, 2810L, 2200L, 2440L, 1111L, 2460L, 
    2210L, 2340L, 1533L, 880L, 2475L, 2350L, 2440L, 1456L, 2320L, 
    2220L, 2990L, 2240L, 2210L, 2630L)), .Names = c("ID", "EC"
), row.names = 40:80, class = "data.frame")
```

How can I create two new df, based on the ID? So I can have two new df named B21T and P1 for example?
I know I can do it with a subset, but if I have many IDs it would take a lot of time.

So I think that what I'm looking for is a way to automatize the subset function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `df` is your data.frame, then just do:

```
df$ID <- droplevels(df$ID)  #  drop unused levels from `ID`
list2env(split(df, df$ID), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the different subsets you want in a `list` and, then extract them from there:

```
#DF <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(12L ...

#all different "ID"s
ids <- as.character(unique(DF$ID))

#create empty list to insert all different subsets
myls <- vector("list", length(ids))

#insert the different subsets
for(i in 1:length(ids)) 
 { 
  myls[[i]] <- DF[DF$ID == ids[i],]
 }

names(myls) <- ids
```

You can accesss the wanted dataframe:

```
> myls$P21
    ID   EC
56 P21 3630
57 P21 3400
...

> myls$P1
   ID   EC
40 P1  953
41 P1  838
...
```

This might take some time, though, if you have really many "ID"s.

**EDIT**
Waaay better than `for` loop is Jilber's answer. Here used as `split(DF, DF$ID, drop = T)`.

Comment: you can replace the `for` loop by `split`. See `?split`.